# How to print a duplicated sheet with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

When I use the code below

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB_Main").Copy _
After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

I end up with a new sheet named `DB_Main (2)`

I am looking for a way to print these 2 sheets from my "Main" sheet using a button.
From sheet `DB_Main`the pages 4 and 5, and from sheet `DB_Main (2)`the pages 4,5,6 and 7.

How can I detect a copied sheet?
Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: I don't understand when "sometimes" is, and what you mean by "pages". Please clarify in your post

Comment: Loop through your sheets and see if name `Like "*(2)"` to check if pages have been replicated. That's the answer to your last sentence. Rest of your question is unclear.

Comment: I'd disagree, that merely shows whether a file exists with a name ending on `(2)`. This is not unlikely to result in a false positive. A better way would be to check if a sheet name exists more than once, using wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy a sheet, it gets automatically the *active* sheet. Assign this to a variable, after that you can do whatever you want:

```
Dim oldWs As Worksheet
Set oldWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB_Main")
oldWs.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
Dim newWs As Worksheet
Set newWs = ActiveSheet
' Rename the sheet if you want
newWs.Name = "I am brand new"
' Print out old Main and copy
wb.Worksheets(Array(oldWs.Name, newWs.Name)).PrintOut
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to loop all sheets and compare the cell A1 if its equal to 1.
Its work like that.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim allshts As Worksheet
For Each allshts In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If allshts .Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
allshts .PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
End If
Next allshts 

End Sub
```